# PHP - How to remove anything after extension (jpg, png, gif, jpeg, svg, ...)

Tags: php

I'm using php 7 and trying to remove anything after extension of urls;

Example

```
    https://website/sites/tag/filename/IMG25.jpg?iabc=gfds
    to 
    https://website/sites/tag/filename/IMG25.jpg
```

or

```
    https://website/sites/tag/filename/IMG25.png&iabc=gfds
    to 
    https://website/sites/tag/filename/IMG25.png
```

or

```
    https://website/sites/tag/filename/IMG25.jpeg&abc=gfds
    to 
    https://website/sites/tag/filename/IMG25.jpeg
```

I'm trying this function

```
$clean_url = preg_replace(
    "/(.+\.(:?jpg|gif|jp2|png|bmp|jpeg|svg)).*$/",
    '',
    $filename
);
```

But this function not working

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: something like "https://website/sites/tag/filename/IMG25.jpg"

Comment: take a look at `parse_url` https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: just explode on ?: `list ($url, $qs) = explode('?', $url);`

Comment: Lots more alternative solutions at the dupe...

Comment: all solution are for removing what after "?"; my question id removing what after extension not the question mark

Comment: Duplicate here isn't a real duplicate, since this asker doesn't want to remove query strings specifically. Am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some adjustments to your regex in order to capture groups and replace the url by only the first group like this :

```
$clean_url = preg_replace(
    "/(.+(\.(jpg|gif|jp2|png|bmp|jpeg|svg)))(.*)$/",
    '${1}',
    $url
);
```

Sample code for all cases :

```
<?php

$urls = [
    "https://website/sites/tag/filename/IMG25.png&iabc=gfds",
    "https://website/sites/tag/filename/IMG25.jpg?iabc=gfds",
    "https://website/sites/tag/filename/IMG25.jpeg&abc=gfds"
];


foreach ($urls as $url){
    $clean_url = preg_replace(
        "/(.+(\.(jpg|gif|jp2|png|bmp|jpeg|svg)))(.*)$/",
        '${1}',
        $url
    );

    echo $clean_url ."\n";

}
```

Comment: my question is not to remove what after "?" the question mark; my question is how to remove what after extension example .jpg&hg=gfd

Comment: i've noticed that you have a `&` in the second and third examples whereas in the first example you have `?`, does it have to work for both cases ?

Comment: I'm trying to remove anything after extension ? or & or ! .....
example I have a link like mysite/img?id=123&file=image.jpg!gh so I want to remove what is after ".jpg"

Comment: i've updated the answer, can you have a look ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

First explode your url string using '?' as a delimiter, than use first element of resulted array.

```
explode('?', $url)[0];
```

Comment: your solution is good for remove after "?" but for me I want to remove anything after extension not question mark

Comment: You are right, my bad, will try to think about another solutions

Comment: First answer now seems to be correct http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9840f2a7c5ae3381f854476c5b553c5645ddc10f